# Unable to set a value in a structure in C. ERROR: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, struct

I have a application that is suppose to store graphic elements. I am having an issue where I cant access a variable in a structure. Here is what i have so far.

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CLib.h"

enum{ RUNNING = 1 };

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

struct Line
{
    Point start;
    Point end;
};

struct GraphicElement
{
    enum{ SIZE = 256 };
    char name[SIZE];
    CStash Lines;   // a Stash of Lines
};

struct VectorGraphic
{
    CStash Elements;    // a Stash of GraphicElements
    };

    void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic*);
    void ReportVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic*);
    void CleanUpVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic*);

    VectorGraphic Image;
int main()
{
    char response;
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    // it's a Stash of GraphicElements  initialize(&(Image.Elements),sizeof(GraphicElement));   
    while (RUNNING)
    {
        printf("\nPlease select an option:\n");
        printf("1. Add a Graphic Element\n");
        printf("2. List the Graphic Elements\n");
        printf("q. Quit\n");
        printf("CHOICE: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &response);

        switch (response)
        {
        case '1':AddGraphicElement(&Image); break;
        case '2':ReportVectorGraphic(&Image); break;
        case 'q':CleanUpVectorGraphic(&Image); return 0;
        default:printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic* pImage){


    int i = 0, counter = 0;
    int xPointStart = 0, yPointStart = 0;
    int xPointEnd = 0, yPointEnd = 0;
    char name[50];
    int lineNumber = 0;


    GraphicElement *pElement = nullptr;
    Line *pLine = nullptr;


    initialize(&(Image.Elements), sizeof(GraphicElement));



    printf("ADDING A Graphic Element\n");
    printf("Please enter the name of the new GraphicElement(<256 characters): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("\n%[^\n]s", &name);
    fflush(stdin);

    strcpy(pElement->name,name);
```

Anytime I try assigning `strcpy(pElement->name,name);` it tells me access violation.

The two other files im working with that cannot be changed and are from a textbook called Thinking in C++.

```
//: C04:CLib.cpp {O}
// Implementation of example C-like library
// Declare structure and functions:
#include "CLib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
// Quantity of elements to add
// when increasing storage:
const int increment = 100;

void initialize(CStash* s, int sz)
{
    s->size = sz;
    s->quantity = 0;
    s->storage = nullptr;
    s->next = 0;
}

int add(CStash* s, const void* element)
{
    if (s->next >= s->quantity) //Enough space left?
        inflate(s, increment);
    // Copy element into storage,
    // starting at next empty space:
    int startBytes = s->next * s->size;
    unsigned char* e = (unsigned char*)element;
    for (int i = 0; i < s->size; i++)
        s->storage[startBytes + i] = e[i];
    s->next++;
    return(s->next - 1); // Index number
}

void* fetch(CStash* s, int index)
{
    // Check index boundaries:
    assert(0 <= index);
    if (index >= s->next)
        return 0; // To indicate the end
    // Produce pointer to desired element:
    return &(s->storage[index * s->size]);
}

int count(CStash* s)
{
    return s->next; // Elements in CStash
}

void inflate(CStash* s, int increase)
{
    assert(increase > 0);
    int newQuantity = s->quantity + increase;
    int newBytes = newQuantity * s->size;
    int oldBytes = s->quantity * s->size;
    unsigned char* b = new unsigned char[newBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < oldBytes; i++)
        b[i] = s->storage[i]; // Copy old to new
    delete[](s->storage); // Old storage
    s->storage = b; // Point to new memory
    s->quantity = newQuantity;
}

void cleanup(CStash* s)
{
    if (s->storage != 0)
    {
        cout << "freeing storage" << endl;
        delete[]s->storage;
    }
} ///:~
```

and the .h file...

```
//: C04:CLib.h
// Header file for a C-like library
// An array-like entity created at runtime

typedef struct CStashTag {
    int size;       // Size of each space
    int quantity;   // Number of storage spaces
    int next;       // Next empty space
    unsigned char* storage;// Dynamically allocated array of bytes
} CStash;

void initialize(CStash* s, int size);
void cleanup(CStash* s);
int add(CStash* s, const void* element);
void* fetch(CStash* s, int index);
int count(CStash* s);
void inflate(CStash* s, int increase);
///:~
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the relevant language tag.

Comment: `GraphicElement *pElement = nullptr; strcpy(pElement->name,name);`. Is the problem not clear? What do you think accessing a null pointer will do?

Comment: What is the question you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GraphicElement *pElement = nullptr;
// ...
strcpy(pElement->name,name);
```

Somewhere between the top line and bottom line above you need to allocate memory for `pElement`.

`pElement = new GraphicElement();`

Also, consider using a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer, given you tagged this `C++`.